# Smallest $\sigma$-algebra such that $X$ is a random variable

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables

Let $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a random variable on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. It could be shown that $\Pi(X) := \{ \{X \leq x\}: x \in \mathbb{R}\} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ is a $\pi$-system. Now, I want to show that $\Pi(X)$ generates $\sigma(X)$.

Notwithstanding that this question is quite related to other [posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2000142/does-the-set-of-inverse-images-of-a-generator-of-a-sigma-algebra-generate-the-si), I have trouble to make ends meet according to the formulation of the above statement.

If I am right, we want to show that
\begin{align}
\sigma(X) = \{X^{-1}(B): B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\}= \sigma(\{\{X\leq x\}:x \in \mathbb{R}\}).
\end{align}
However, I can not express how $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is generated $\neq \sigma\{ \{X \leq x\} :x \in \mathbb{R}\}$. Due to this indistinctness, I am not sure how to interchange the inverse image $X^{-1}$ in and out the $\sigma$ to find the result. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly $\Pi(X) \subset \sigma(X)$, which implies $\sigma(\Pi(X)) \subset \sigma(X)$.

The interesting part is the other inclusion. Let $M = \{ B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \mid X^{-1}(B) \in \sigma(\Pi(X))\}$. By definition, $M$ contains all intervals of the form $(-\infty, x]$. This implies
$$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) = \sigma(\{(-\infty, x] \mid x \in \mathbb{R}\}) \subset \sigma(M) = M \subset \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),$$
since $M$ is itself a $\sigma$-Algebra (this is easy to verify).

Now we have proven $M = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, which means $\sigma(X) \subset \sigma(\Pi(X))$.

Comment: Thanks Dominik! I am wondering why $\Pi(X) \subseteq \sigma(X)$ is obvious. Intuitively, this is not directly clear for me, can you provide some more details?

Comment: We have $\{X \le x\} = X^{-1}((-\infty, x])$ and $(-\infty, x]$ is a Borel-set.